# How can i set up Struts2.5 without configuring Spring

Tags: struts2

Writing a simple HelloWorld application using Struts2.5. Getting the following error.

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
FATAL StrutsSpringObjectFactory ********** FATAL ERROR STARTING UP STRUTS-SPRING INTEGRATION **********
Looks like the Spring listener was not configured for your web app! 
Nothing will work until WebApplicationContextUtils returns a valid ApplicationContext.
You might need to add the following to web.xml: 
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
ERROR DefaultConversionPropertiesProcessor Conversion registration error
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:177)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultTypeConverterCreator.createTypeConverter(DefaultTypeConverterCreator.java:40)
    ......
INFO: Server startup in [11,384] milliseconds
```

Following is struts.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="reg" class="action.EmployeeController">
            <result name="input">/input.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

How can it be resolved without configuring Spring?

Comment: Do you have a Struts listener configured?

Comment: No, how can i do it?

Comment: My web.xml file was wrong, contained welcome-file-list. Removed it and it somehow worked!

Comment: The error message says that you are missing dependency for log4j2.

Comment: Yes, but that error won't cause the program to terminate.